# Open ID implementation feedback

Tags: c#, openid

Hi I have found an article on implementing OpenID on my C# site http://madskristensen.net/post/OpenID-implementation-in-Csharp-and-ASPNET.aspx

I have a few basic needs, mainly need to add some sort of security groups to my user profiles and the like, and I think I can do it using Open ID.

My question is has anyone done much work with Open ID, how well have the users accepted it and when would you or when would you not recommend using it on a site?

Comment: Don't use Mads Kristensen's OpenID implementation.  It's got serious security holes as discussed in the comments on that page and as he was willing to admit by posting "don't use this" on the top of his page.  The only secure OpenID library for .NET I know of is DotNetOpenAuth.

Comment: (and yes, of course I'm biased toward DotNetOpenAuth as its author, but I'm also very familiar with several openid libraries, including ones in .NET and this is an objective analysis IMO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you check out http://openidux.dotnetopenauth.net/ which shows an ASP.NET web site that does OpenID in a very easy way (it passes the "my mom and dad can do it" test).  It's free for your use in your web site, and included in the [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net) project.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for a consumer site. The acceptance is terrible. Out of tens thousands of logins we get every day, only a few dozens are done over OpenID. Half may be our testers.

The problem is that most consumers don't care what protocol you use to login and most of them just have no idea what OpenID means.

We are changing to OpenID 2.0 and will remove the notion of OpenID. It's going to be Google or AOL login, instead of OpenID. I think we can improve the adoption by hiding OpenID.

If your site is for bloggers or geeks, I think OpenID will be a good choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no my site is for general public, and your exprerience is my concern, to go through all the effort for nough?